# Is there a simple, intuitive reason for why the total induced charge is always equal to the hypothetical image charge in the method of images?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, method-of-images

In the method of images, the total induced charge (actual) on the surface of the conductor is always equal to the image charge (hypothetical). Can this be explained intuitively?

Comment: can you clarify please? At what situation do you think?